# How to get another context path in factory method?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Let's imagine that we have `sap.m.UploadCollection` and we bind the data to this collection which is done like this:

```
bind: function () {
    this._oUploadCollection.bindAggregation("items", {
        path: "/attachments",
        factory: jQuery.proxy(this._bindUploadCollectionItem, this)
    });
},
```

The example of the binding data is here:

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "size": 123,
            "filename": "pdf.pdf",
            "id": "pdfId"
        },
        {
            "size": 440,
            "filename": "text.txt",
            "id": "textId"
        }
    ],
    "source":"personWhoAddedAttachments"
}
```

So, in `_bindUploadCollectionItem` I successfully can get `size`, `filename` and `id` by `oContext.getProperty("nameOfParameter")`, but cannot get `source`:

```
_bindUploadCollectionItem: function (sID, oContext) {
    return new sap.m.UploadCollectionItem({
        "id": oContext.getProperty("id"),               
        "fileName": oContext.getProperty("filename"),                              
        "attributes": [                                          
        {
             "title": "author",
             "text": oContext.getProperty("../source") // <- problem
        }]
   });
},
```

So, because I bind `attachments` it is kind of clear that I could not get `source`, *but how to reach it if I need it?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a little on what property of the model you want to get to. If it is really like you described it and the target property is in the `/source` absolute model path, then the easiest way of getting it inside the factory function is by using: `oContext.getModel().getProperty("/source")`.

If you need something which is inside a collection (and somehow depends on the current context), you can achieve an effect similar to the `..` path construct that you tried by using something along the lines:

```js
var sPath = oContext.getPath(),
    sParent = sPath.substring(0, sPath.lastIndexOf("/")),
    sText = oContext.getModel().getProperty(sParent + "/source");
return new sap.m.UploadCollectionItem({
    "id": oContext.getProperty("id"),               
    "fileName": oContext.getProperty("filename"),                              
    "attributes": [{
         "title": "author",
         "text": sText
    }]
});
```

You basically obtain the parent object path by searching for the last `/` inside the path. You can apply this repeatedly (or use a split, pop some elements, followed by a join) to get to the ancestors (e.g. parent of parent).

Comment: Thanks, oContext.getModel().getProperty("/source") made it working!